# R: Select values from data table in range

Tags: r

I have a data table in R:

```
name    date
----    ----
John    1156649280
Adam    1255701960
...etc...
```

I want to get all of the rows that have a date within a range. In SQL, I might say `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date > 5 AND date < 15`

What is the equivalent in R, to select rows based on the range of values in a particular column?

Comment: Note that the sqldf package allows you to apply SQL to R data frames.  e.g. `library(sqldf); sqldf("select * from mytable where date > 5 and date < 15")` . See home page at http://sqldf.googlecode.com .

Comment: @G. Grothendieck very cool; I figured *someone* had written something like this, thank you for the link

Comment: I think it should be noted that data there is an R package **data.table** that creates data objects of class data.table. It is not clear if you were using the term "data table" informally and actually meant  **data.frame**, or if you are actually asking about **data.table** objects.

Comment: @Ista I was using data.table, but then used as.data.frame(mytable) in order to be consistent with the answers below.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Construct some data

> df <- data.frame(         name=c("John",
>   "Adam"),      date=c(3, 5) )

Extract exact matches:

```
subset(df, date==3)

  name date
1 John    3
```

Extract matches in range:

```
subset(df, date>4 & date<6)

  name date
2 Adam    5
```

The following syntax produces identical results:

```
df[df$date>4 & df$date<6, ]

  name date
2 Adam    5
```

Answer (score 17):

Lots of options here, but one of the easiest to follow is `subset`. Consider:

```
> set.seed(43)
> df <- data.frame(name = sample(letters, 100, TRUE), date = sample(1:500, 100, TRUE))
> 
> subset(df, date > 5 & date < 15)
   name date
11    k   10
67    y   12
86    e    8
```

You can also insert logic directly into the index for your data.frame. The comma separates the rows from columns. We just have to remember that R indexes rows first, then columns. So here we are saying rows with date > 5 & < 15 and then all columns:

```
df[df$date > 5 & df$date < 15 ,]
```

I'd also recommend checking out the help pages for subset, `?subset` and the logical operators `?"&"`

Answer (score 5):

One should also consider another intuitive way to do this using `filter()` from `dplyr`. Here are some examples:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(name = sample(letters, 100, TRUE),
                 date = sample(1:500, 100, TRUE))
library(dplyr)
filter(df, date < 50) # date less than 50
filter(df, date %in% 50:100) # date between 50 and 100
filter(df, date %in% 1:50 & name == "r") # date between 1 and 50 AND name is "r"
filter(df, date %in% 1:50 | name == "r") # date between 1 and 50 OR name is "r"

# You can also use the pipe (%>%) operator
df %>% filter(date %in% 1:50 | name == "r")
```

Comment: `date %in% 1:50` checks that date is contained in the sequential vector of integers between 1 and 50, *not* that it's in the continuous interval between those two endpoints. e.g. `3.5 %in% 1:50` evaluates false

Answer (score 0):

Another option using [`between`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/between.html) from dplyr like this (data from @andrie):

```r
df <- data.frame(name=c("John", "Adam"), date=c(3, 5))

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(between(date, 4, 6))
#>   name date
#> 1 Adam    5

df[between(df$date, 4, 6), ]
#>   name date
#> 2 Adam    5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>