# How to use conditional sentences in r

Tags: r

Lets say I have a data frame with two variables x & y and a factor f with two levels a & b.
I want R to, for example `plot(x,y)` only when `f==a`.  Usually I subset the data frame, but I want to find more efficient way to do it.  I'm pursuing two ways but with no success.

I'm trying to use

```
for(i in f=="a"){plot(x,y)
}
```

But it plots with both a and b
I'm also trying to use

```
ifelse(f=="a",plot(x,y),f)
```

but it returns this error message, which I don't understand.

```
Error in ans[test & !nas] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test &  : 
  replacement has length zero
```

Comment: ifelse isn't meant for that. It's for vectorised conditional evaluation. Something like: big=ifelse(Z>100,"BIG","SMALL") - which returns a vector the same length as Z with each element either "BIG" or "SMALL". Your ifelse is trying to apply vector selection to the plot function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204953/r-select-values-from-data-table-in-range/5204997#5204997) for further details. There are several ways to do this. One thing to note is that assuming all of your columns come from the same `data.frame`, you have to reference the `data.frame` object first, not just the columns you are trying to plot. For instance, you could have a `data.frame` named `df` which contains the columns `x,y,f` and then also have different objects in your environment named `x,y,f` that were entirely different and unrelated to your `data.frame`. Here are a few examples:

```
#Sample data
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), f = sample(letters[1:2], 100, TRUE))

#With subset
df.a <- subset(df, f == "a")
plot(df.a$x, df.a$y)

#or
#Or logical indexing
plot(df$x[df$f == "a"] , df$y[df$f == "a"])

#or

#Combining with and logical indexing
with(df[df$f == "a" ,], plot(x,y))
```

Comment: Thanks Chase, sorry for being too vague. Really appreciate you help and your review.